# Url launcher not working iOS flutter devices, can't send email or make calls

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I try to launch an email page and make calls. I tried URL launcher to do the same thing on ios as it worked on android.

I use this example of URL launcher:

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Text('${_con.restaurant.phone} \n${_con.restaurant.mobile}',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        SizedBox(
            width: 42,
            height: 42,
            child: FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: () {
                launch("tel:${_con.restaurant.mobile}");
            },
            child: Icon(
                Cretello_app.contact2,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                size: 24,
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.9),
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            ),
        ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Are you testing on simulator ? It won't work on simulator.

Comment: @danypata Wow! so i need to try it on real device?

Comment: if you're testing the email or the phone, you'll have to test on a real phone. I think the email would work on the simulator if you set an email account on the simulator, but the phone won't work.

Comment: @danypata Thanks, I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Simulator doesn't have the default email and phone app installed. That's why `tel` and `mailto` links can't be opened in the iOS Simulator as mentioned in the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#supported-url-schemes).

> URL schemes are only supported if there are apps installed on the
> device that can support them. For example, iOS simulators don't have a
> default email or phone apps installed, so can't open `tel`: or `mailto:`
> links.